# How to mount a virtual hard disk?

Tags: mount, virtualization

Is it possible to mount a virtual hard disk (VHD, HDD, VDI, VMDK) on Ubuntu? How can this be done?

Comment: Have you searched Google? It abounds with guides on mounting [VMDK, VDI, VHD, and raw](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-mount-virtualbox-drive-image-vdi-in-ubuntu-12-1012-04.html) disk image files on Ubuntu.

Comment: I have searched google, but I did not find like your result.
Thanks :)

Comment: Ubuntugeek link for VHD above failed.

Answer (score 21):

According to [this wikibooks article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Mounting_an_image_on_the_host):

> Linux and other Unix-like hosts can mount images created with the raw
> format type using a loopback device. From a root login (or using
> sudo), mount a loopback with an offset of 32,256.
>
> ```
> mount -o loop,offset=32256 /path/to/image.img /mnt/mountpoint
> ```

> For other types of qemu images, you can use qemu-nbd
>
> ```
> modprobe nbd max_part=16
> qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 image.qcow2
> partprobe /dev/nbd0
> mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt/image
> ```

Plus, usually, you can convert image from one format to another.

```
raw - (default) the raw format is a plain binary image of the disc 
       image, and is very portable. 
       On filesystems that support sparse files, 
       images in this format only use the 
       space actually used by the data recorded in them.
cloop -     Compressed Loop format, mainly used for reading Knoppix 
       and similar live CD image formats
cow - copy-on-write format, supported for historical reasons only and
       not available to QEMU on Windows
qcow - the old QEMU copy-on-write format, supported for 
       historical reasons and superseded by qcow2
qcow2 - QEMU copy-on-write format with a range of special features, 
       including the ability to take multiple snapshots, smaller 
       images on filesystems that don't support sparse files, 
       optional AES encryption, and optional zlib compression
vmdk - VMware 3 & 4, or 6 image format, for exchanging images 
       with that product
vdi - VirtualBox 1.1 compatible image format, for exchanging 
       images with VirtualBox.
```

I found this solution for (VirtualBox) .VDI when I searched, on [this website](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/vdi.shtml):

> ```
> modprobe nbd max_part=16
> qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 /path/to/some.vdi
> mount -o loop /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt
> # do stuff
> umount /mnt
> qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
> rmmod nbd
> ```

The same as "Qemu's way" commands. No borders!

Comment: As of today (November, 2022) this solution still works! Maybe it is worth adding that demanded partition is not neccesserilly nbd0p1. List all partitions: `ls /dev/nbd0*` and try to mount them one by one (`umount /mnt/image` if you get what you don't want).

Answer (score 9):

This is on **Ubuntu 16.04**.

Install and mount using `affuse`:

```
sudo apt-get install afflib-tools
sudo affuse /path/file.vmdk /mnt/vmdk
```

Check sector size:

```
sudo fdisk -l /mnt/vmdk/file.vmdk.raw

# example

Disk file.vmdk.raw: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000da525

Device       Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/mnt/vmdk/file.vmdk.raw1 *     2048 41943039 41940992  20G 83 Linux
```

Multiply sectorsize and startsector. In this example it would be 2048*512:

```
$ echo 2048*512 | bc
1048576
```

Mount using that offset:

```
sudo mount -o ro,loop,offset=1048576 /mnt/vmdk/file.raw /mnt/vmdisk
```

Disk should now be mounted and readable on `/mnt/vmdisk`

Comment: great!!! did it for me on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: This is not working for me on 16.04.5 for my .vmdk...works through the fdisk step, and the main partition of my VM, the one I want to mount, also starts at 2048, but `mount -o ro,loop,offset=1048576 ./foo.raw /mnt/foo` fails with `only root can use "--options" option`. With `sudo`, it fails with `failed to setup loop device: Permission denied`.

Comment: at least on ubuntu 22.04, `affuse` doesn't support `vmdk` files

Answer (score 6):

You can also use qemu:

### For `.vdi`

```
sudo modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd1 ./linux_box/VM/image.vdi
```

if they are not installe you can install them (on Ubuntu is this comand)

```
sudo apt install qemu-utils
```

and then mount it

```
mount /dev/nbd1p1 /mnt
```

### For `.vmdk`

```
sudo modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -r -c /dev/nbd1 ./linux_box/VM/image.vmdk
```

notice tha I use the option `-r` that's because **VMDK version 3 must be read only** to be able to be mounted by qemu

and then I mount it

```
mount /dev/nbd1p1 /mnt
```

I use `nbd1` because `nbd0` sometimes gives 'mount: special device /dev/nbd0p1 does not exist'

### For .ova

```
tar -tf image.ova
tar -xvf image.ova
```

The above will extract the `.vmdk` disk and then mount that.

Answer (score 2):

For `vmdk` and `vhd` files, I only got lucky with the `kpartx` command below:

```
sudo kpartx -a -v <image-flat.vmdk>
```

Check the output for the `losetup`, it should contain loop device `/dev/loop0`; also check `sudo blkid` for partition `/dev/mapper/loop0p1`, then use it in the mount command:

```
sudo mount -o rw /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/vmdk
```

Where /mnt/vmdk is your mount point, to be created with `sudo mkdir /mnt/vmdk` if non-existent.

[source at commandlinefu.com (kpartx and mount command)](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/13718/mount-a-vmware-virtual-disk-.vmdk-file-on-a-linux-box)

Unmount with:

```
sudo umount /mnt/vmdk
sudo kpartx -d -v <image-flat.vmdk>
```

Comment: Just tested this method with `vhd`, it works!

Comment: just tested with vmdk and it didn't work. it seems that kpartx only supports raw images (without metadata and space-saving tricks). this also makes sense because kpartx is not more than a partition-aware wrapper over losetup (loopback devices), and these can only support raw files