# Clonezilla Copy Ubuntu 20.04 install to another computer

Tags: 20.04, clonezilla

I have 2 servers, serv1 and serv2. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on both. Serv2 came almost a year after serv1 and with a CPU that I thought would perform better. But after initial testing it was actually slower. To remove all differences between the 2 servers I decided to clone the NVMe drive of serv1 and install it on serv2 NVMe drive. I used Clonezilla create an image of serv1 and install it on serv2 and it seemed to work.

The issue is when I start serv2 it does not boot into Ubuntu. Even when I select the boot menu the NVMe drive does not show up. If I boot with an Ubuntu Live USB I can mount the drive and see that everything is there. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to do `nano [mounted drive location]/etc/fstab` in a live CD/USB

And then modifiy the UUID of the mounted partitions there, as :

> The GUID UUID and associated label refer to a partition, but not the partition's contents. A new partition on the same disk, or a partition on a new disk will have a new GUID UUID. The same partition could hold one file system one day and another on a different day. It only exists for GPT formatted disks, but not for legacy partitioned disks. There's usually no more utility here than specifying root=/dev/sda1 or root=8:1.

[source](https://serverfault.com/a/607402/604280)

As you created a new set of partitions, on a different disk, Ubuntu finds no partitions to mount, and as no OS is loaded, fails silently

You'll need to harvest your disk to find which partition is mounted where (using `lsblk`) then [to find the UUID](https://serverfault.com/a/4253/604280)

After that replace the corresponding string after `UUID=` on the fstab on each line

and reboot

Comment: So clonezilla changed the UUID of the NVMe drive to match the UUID of the drive on serv1. So fstab matched did not need any changes.

Comment: Yes, Clonezilla actually done nothing as UUID is unique to a single hardware partition, when created a partition will have a different UUID (those of `s2`), and maybe you'll need to change GRUB boot UUID too

Comment: How would I go about changing GRUB boot UUID?

Comment: @TylerM There is an answer that will help you with a nice script https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140273/how-to-change-uuid-in-the-boot-grub-grub-cfg

Comment: So the UUID in grub.cfg and fstab both match the UUID of the drive...