# How Can the GRUB configuration be ideally adjusted after copying from one SSD unto another to make a backup OS disk

Tags: boot, bootloader, boot-repair, clonezilla, cloning

I want to make a backup copy of one disk to another using the [dd mode of Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone/advanced/05-advanced-param.php), this using the advanced options of "e2, j2, icds, and iefi" which have their descriptions in the advanced menu of Clonezilla, [referenced in that link](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone/advanced/05-advanced-param.php):

1. "e2": sfdisk uses CHS of hard drive from EDD (for non-GRUB boot
   loader) [CHS are the Cylinders, Heads, and Sectors](https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/osdn/clonezilla/64766/clonezilla_doc_v1.1.pdf) of the EDD
   (assuming Existing Disk Drive).
2. "j2": Clone Hidden Data between the
   MBR and the first partition
3. "icds": Skip checking destination disk
   size before creating the partition table "
4. iefi": Skip updating entries in NVI boot RAM after cloning

After completing the disk-to-disk clone from Clonezilla, there is still the issue that the GRUB UUID's are not correct, since GRUB still has the configuration of the drive that was copied.

From the Stack Exchange Ask Ubuntu Question, "[How to change UUID in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140273/how-to-change-uuid-in-the-boot-grub-grub-cfg)", there are a number of interesting approaches.

For instance there is the answer from [that link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140273/how-to-change-uuid-in-the-boot-grub-grub-cfg) from "Pierre ALBARÈDE":

> You can directly change the UUID in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` as you did.
> `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is not updated automatically.  However, if you
> want to preserve bootability you also need to change the UUID
> accordingly elsewhere, for example, with EFI/UEFI booting, in
> `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` and `/etc/fstab`.

Also, "Vojtech Trefny" documents how it is possible to boot to GRUB from the computer's BIOS boot menu in his answer to the question, "[How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)"

> Menu will appear if you press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during loading
> Grub, if you boot using BIOS. When your system boots using UEFI, press
> <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
>
> For permanent change you'll need to edit your `/etc/default/grub`
> file:
>
> Place a `#` symbol at the start of line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` to
> comment it out. If that line doesn't exist, then you can comment out
> this line instead: `# GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`, and then change
> `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=5`, for instance, to give the grub
> menu a 5 second timeout before it automatically logs you in.
>
> Save changes and run `sudo update-grub` to apply changes.
>
> Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Is the answer to the question "[How to change UUID in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140273/how-to-change-uuid-in-the-boot-grub-grub-cfg)" given by "Pierre ALBARÈDE" the best approach?  There are a number of options in that article, and I am still a little confused as to what the best approach from there or from somewhere else is.  Still. when I issue the command "sudo blkid" to get the UUID's for all the disks on the system, I get an entry for the EFI (boot) partition sdc5 as:

> sudo blkid

> /dev/sdc5: UUID="1887-E4A1" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="d05239a5-e32f-4d3c-bc80-76bca4afb0b8"

There is the UUID and there is the Part UUID.  Which UUID needs to be added to the GRUB menu?  (I guess that I could inspect the menu of the source disk that I am duplicating to figure this out, but I am hoping that this part of the question can also be addressed in the answer.)

1. The etc/defualt/grub file can be modified to allow a choice of boot options and "e" can be used to successfully boot to Ubuntu form the disk:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

#enable OS PROBER
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

After that, the answer to the question "[How to change UUID in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140273/how-to-change-uuid-in-the-boot-grub-grub-cfg)" given by "Pierre ALBARÈDE" can be used to update the UUID's in:
Directly change the UUID's in **/boot/grub/grub.cfg** (since **/boot/grub/grub.cfg** is not updated automatically), and also in **/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg** and also in  **/etc/fstab**.  Then run **sudo update-grub**.

Am I missing something in the steps needed to update the files that **sudo update-grub** does not update and then run **sudo update-grub** once booted into the new disk.

*What is the best approach, so that the new cloned disk can boot, just like the old one, with the proper UUID's in each of the respective's configuration files?*

Comment: I prefer new clean install & rsync data, list of installed apps, & any server apps in / (root)  from your normal backup into new install. Proves backup is complete when you still have working install. And avoids all the issues of updating UUIDs/GUIDs in fstab, swap, & ESP (if UEFI). And you you clone again to refresh copy, you have to go thru the change of UUIDs again. If you do not rsync anything with UUID/GUIDs, you can then regularly update "clone".