# Failed to load rescue target after fsck

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, fsck

Things happened:

1. Get stuck on the black screen, press the power button to shutdown and reboot.
2. Get the message "filesystem on /dev/sda3 requires a manual fsck".
3. Run command `fsck -yf /dev/sda3` and `exit`.
4. Get the message "Failed to load rescue target, freezing".

Things I have tried for solving this problem:

1. Add `systemd.unit=rescue.target` in the kernel line and boot. Still got the "Failed to load rescue target, freezing" message.
2. Add `systemd.unit=emergency.target` in the kernel line and boot. Still got the "Failed to load rescue target, freezing" message.
3. In GRUB, run commands `set boot=(hd0,gpt3)`, `set prefix=(hd0,gpt3)/boot/grub`, `insmod normal` and `normal`, back to the menu, get additional "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu Advanced Options", choose either of the four options (two "Ubuntu" and two "Ubuntu Advanced Options") will get the "Failed to load rescue target, freezing" message.
4. Add `init=/bin/bash` in the kernel line, boot, and run the command `mount -n -o remount,rw /`. Not able to run `fsck`: "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error". Not able to run `passwd`: "Permission denied password unchanged".

The full error message when trying to boot normally: (typed manually)

```
[0.048909] ACPI Exception: AE_BAD_PARAMETER, Could not install PciConfig handler for Root Bridge PCI0 (20170831/evrgnini-245)
[1.226507] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
/dev/sda3: recovering journal
/dev/sda3: clean, 139776/6545408 files, 1649034/26163200 blocks
[4.271298] systemd[260]: /lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan failed with exit status 127.
[4.420902] systemd[1]: Failed to load default target: No such file or directory
[4.420938] systemd[1]: Failed to load rescue target: No such file or directory
[!!!!!!] Failed to load rescue target, freezing.
[4.429053] systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
```

Environment:

Windows 10 / Ubuntu 18.04 dual systems

If more information is needed, please tell me.

Comment: Have you tried booting a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media) and running the `fsck` (file system check) from there?  Rather than using power button to shutdown, did you try sysrq keys to safely umount & shutdown (ie. reisub or equiv.)

Comment: Just tried running `fsck` in a live CD system, nothing changed. And "using power button to shutdown" has already happened.

Comment: I have already reinstalled Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have TV Card in your system with kodi boot, tvhead? If this is the case, change the configuration `wait for boot tv = 20 sec; 20; sec `
Freezing occurs when the tv card cannot find a connection; it requires more time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem when accidentally removed whole folder `/usr/lib/systemd/system`.

I eventually succeeded to fix it:

- created the twin-VM version (Ubuntu 20.04 in my case),
- mounted into it the original VM's file system as virtual disk,
- simply copied the `/usr/lib/systemd/system` folder into mounted file system.

In 2nd step I made use of the following: [How to mount a virtual hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202571/how-to-mount-a-virtual-hard-diskk).

Answer (score -1):

1. Make ubuntu<your_ubuntu_version> live usb
2. boot using live usb then choose "Try ubuntu"
3. "search the missing file path on internet"
4. Open folder in ubuntu and go to " + other locations "
5. copy missing files from usb to your ubuntu drive
6. if ask permission to copy then use " sudo -H nautilus " in terminal. A new
   folder is open with root access...use this folder to copy-paste.
7. """"""""""""""""""""""""reboot"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
8. follow same for other missing files.....

Comment: What do you mean by *"search the missing file path on internet"*???