# sdb Attached SCSI disk. But I can't find it anywhere

Tags: usb, mount, external-hdd, sata, scsi

I'm trying to attach external HDD with a new cable I bought on Amazon, JSAUX USB 3.0 to SATA Adapter.

syslog says it was attached as sdb, but I don't see it anywhere.

```
kernel: [ 2839.039779] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

tried

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo parted -l
```

But the attached disk is absent.

If I try my luck and mount sdb anyway, I get error message below.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/external/
mount: /media/external: can't read superblock on /dev/sdb.
```

I found some unrelated solutions to the above error message, but those solve bad superblock, provided the device is recognised (by gparted etc).

But my problems is that the hdd is not recognised.

My syslog says

```
[ 2803.894485] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 2803.923004] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0715, bcdDevice= 1.53
[ 2803.923006] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2803.923007] usb 2-1: Product: VLI Product String
[ 2803.923008] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: VLI Manufacture String
[ 2803.923008] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 000000123AD4
[ 2803.928360] scsi host2: uas
mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1"
mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 5 was not an MTP device
mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1" mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 5 was not an MTP device
kernel: [ 2807.076873] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access              VirtualDisk           PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
kernel: [ 2807.078743] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
kernel: [ 2807.079987] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
kernel: [ 2807.079993] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
kernel: [ 2807.080678] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
kernel: [ 2807.080919] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
kernel: [ 2807.080930] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
kernel: [ 2807.081359] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
dbus-daemon[781]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=782 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
dbus-daemon[781]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
kernel: [ 2837.966519] sd 2:0:0:0: tag#3 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
kernel: [ 2837.966528] sd 2:0:0:0: tag#3 CDB: Inquiry 12 01 00 00 40 00
kernel: [ 2837.966597] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD IN 
kernel: [ 2837.966604] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 CDB: ATA command pass through(12)/Blank a1 08 2e 00 01 00 00 00 00 ec 00 00
kernel: [ 2837.982436] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
kernel: [ 2839.011105] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
kernel: [ 2839.037551] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
kernel: [ 2839.039779] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

UPDATE:

lsblk output is below

```
$ lsblk -ape7 -o +FSUSE%,STATE,MODEL
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT FSUSE% STATE   MODEL
/dev/sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk                   running ST1000LM035-1RK1
├─/dev/sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi      1%         
└─/dev/sda2   8:2    0   931G  0 part /              3%         
/dev/sdb      8:16   0         0 disk                   running VirtualDisk
/dev/sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom                    running PLDS_DVD+_-RW_DU
```

Comment: For what it might be worth; do `$ lsblk -ape7 -o +FSUSE%,STATE,MODEL` and add the output as a code block in your question. Note that a `mount` on a `disk` (as listed by lsblk) will produce the `can't read superblock` error (but it may succeed if the disk has no partition-table, and has a formatted filesystem in that state - a special case).

Comment: One more thing: Does this disk have at least one "known working" partition on it?

Comment: yes, the disk has a working partition, it is main disk from my old pc. Just adding the edit with lsblk output.

Comment: So a "Virtualdisk" you might try what is in this posting https://askubuntu.com/questions/202571/how-to-mount-a-virtual-hard-disk - you might get lucky.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=VirtualDisk

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the manufacturer and identified the problem with their support.

The cable was designed only for small HDDs 2.5 inch. So my 3.5 inch WD's solid parts were probably too heavy.

My HDD was basically not supported :(